# how to create setup in wpf winforms?

Tags: wpf

I have an wpf winforms appln i need to create exe for that
  How to Create Setup.msi  in WPF winform appln?

Answer (score 1):

Create a setup project. See this Microsoft KB [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353).